# Security Issue: Ubuntu 20.04 missing power setting to lock screen when lid closed

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

In 19.10 and before, when I closed the laptop lid, the computer would lock the screen and suspend. Now, it suspends, but when I (or anyone else) opens the lid, the session resumes without requiring a password. There used to be a setting under Power for specifying what to do when the laptop lid is closed. I couldn't find it since upgrading to 20.04. Where is this setting? I need to lockscreen and suspend when I close the lid.

Comment: Does it require password when you suspend using other methods?

Comment: In my case when resuming from suspend it never asks for a password,

Comment: In my case when resuming from suspend it never asks for a password, regardless of how the computer was suspended. "Lock screen on Suspend" is checked in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to `Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock` and enable item `Lock Screen on Suspend` - it works well.

Comment: yAnTar - Under Settings, there is no Screen Lock. There is "Displays", but no submenu for locking screen.
Under Power, there is:
Dim Screen When Inactive (not selected)
Automatic Suspend (When on battery power)
Power Button Behavior (Suspend)

Comment: pomsky - It does not require a password when I suspend using the taskbar's Power Off/Log Out->Suspend method either.

Comment: @Chelmite Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock